# IMAGE PDF to LaTeX Conversion

Tags: conversion

What toolchains are available to convert scans to LaTeX
I am looking for a freeware way to convert PDFs (via OCR and other methods) to LaTeX.

The scanned documents

- are in PDF form.
- have a resolution of about 300 to 600dpi.
- contain only few mathematical expressions.
- contain pictures and text.

I can work with Windows or Ubunto equally fine.
My research so far turned up [InftyReader](http://www.inftyreader.org/) and [writer2latex](http://writer2latex.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: This is probably the wrong place to ask, but nonetheless; It might be helpful if you can show us some of your "Image PDFs", so we can judge the possibilities. Are they images or pages from a document which you need to convert?

Comment: Are you talking about reading in text from a scanned document into a LaTeX document or including images that are pdfs in a LaTeX document?

Comment: @Habi: The pages are copyrighted and the resolution of PDFs pages are 300 dpi to 600 dpi. I have need to convert pages as well as images.

Comment: Do you have lots of mathematical expressions in your pages?  Or is it mostly text?  Can you make a typical example with other contents than (your, I guess?) copyrighted content, so that we see what a typical use case would look like?  For instance, it would be useful to know how "clean" the image is, how elaborate the layout and mathematics are, etc.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch Mathematical expressions are very less and images are simple grayscale mode only. I have [PDF import plugins](extensions.services.openoffice.org/project/pdfimport) in OpenOffice. Now i have found [writer2latex](http://writer2latex.sourceforge.net/) can convert odt to latex format.

Comment: You don't answer to whether those are scans of printed text, or obtained from, e.g., word/open office/other documents.

Comment: If these are scans (and they probably are), I think the most you'll get would be OCR of the text. I dint see aby way of getting useful LaTeX code for font sizes, margins, etc.

Comment: @Bala I really don't see why you'd need to convert *copyrighted* pages to LaTeX (i.e. I see it, but it might be for the wrong reasons). I think your best bet is with the InftyReader mentioned in your question or any other OCR software like [Tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) and manual editing afterwards.

Comment: After long time research i have found <a href="http://www.outsch.org/2010/09/20/poppler-utils-0-15-for-windows/">www.outsch.org/2010/09/20/poppler-utils-0-15-for-windows/</a> and <a href="http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdftohtml/forums/forum/150220/topic/4799038"> and downloaded the `pdftohtml` and working fine in windows.